# How to put date formatter on th:field in themeleaf implementation

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In form have th:placeholder. In that field passing date parameter and want to format this field in "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;">
    <label class="sr-only" for="datetimepicker">Check In</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="datetimepicker" th:placeholder="${search.getDateCheckIn()}" style="width:100%;"/>
    <input type='text' th:field="*{dateCheckIn}" id="datetimepicker1" hidden="hidden"/>
</div>
```

prototype of `search.getDateCheckIn()`

```
public Date getDateCheckIn() {
    return dateCheckIn;
}
```

Any suggestion for applying date format for given field at view level in themeleaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to format dates using Thymeleaf is explained [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dates).

If you want to format the placeholder to dd/MM/yyyy, it would be:

```
th:placeholder="${#dates.format(search.getDateCheckIn(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"
```